# Multiple operation on single column in Flux

Tags: influxdb, flux

Trying to recreate some of the basics in Flux compared to InfluxQL is quite a stretch at present.

I can’t work out how to ask for multiple projections.

```
select max(temp) - min(temp) from my_measurement
```

I’m not sure how to go about this in Flux.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Option 1 - built in function

The simplest way is probably to use the built-in [spread](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/cloud/reference/flux/stdlib/built-in/transformations/aggregates/spread/) function:

> The spread() function outputs the difference between the minimum and maximum values in a specified column.

```js
from(bucket: "example-bucket")
  |> range(start: -5m)
  |> filter(fn: (r) =>
    r._measurement == "cpu" and
    r._field == "usage_system"
  )
  |> spread()
```

#### Option 2 - custom function

If you want complete control over the logic, creating a [custom aggregate function](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/query-data/flux/custom-functions/custom-aggregate/) for this would work. Something along the lines of this (assuming your data has at least one positive value):

```js
delta = (tables=<-, outputField="delta") =>
  tables
    |> reduce(
      // Define the initial accumulator record
      identity: {
        maximum: 0.0,
        minimum: math.maxfloat,
        delta: 0.0
      },
      fn: (r, accumulator) => ({
        // update max and min on each reduce loop
        maximum: if r._value > accumulator.maximum then r._value else accumulator.maximum,
        minimum: if r._value < accumulator.minimum then r._value else accumulator.minimum,
        // take the delta
        delta: accumulator.maximum - accumulator.minimum
      })
    )
    // Set the _field label of the output table to to the value
    // provided in the outputField parameter
    |> set(key: "_field", value: outputField)
    // Rename delta column to _value
    |> rename(columns: {delta: "_value"})
    // Optionally, Drop the max and min columns since they are no longer needed
//     |> drop(columns: ["maximum", "minimum"])


// apply your custom function wherever you want to calculate a delta
from(bucket: "my-bucket")
  |> range(start: -1h)
// optionally filter here to isolate the field that you want 
// |> filter(fn: (r) => <predicate>)
  |> delta()
```

This would yield the delta between the max and min values from the last `range` worth of data (-1h in this example). Once you create the custom function, you can use it on any stream.